# How could I use lapply with two parameters?

Tags: r, apply

I have a list with the names of my files and an array with some integers i want to use every time I open a file. When I open file1 I want it to use numbers[1], when I open file 14 I want it to open numbers[14].
I have tried to create n inside the function in which I will use lapply, but not knowing how to have an index to know which file I am reading, I discarded it. Then I tried to use mapply but it creates twice as many elements as I want.
I want to execute my function and every time I use the n index element of my fnames and the n index of my array numbers. I want you to save the result in a list.

My function opens a file and calculates the data in that file based on the value of n corresponding to that file (in a while). That's why I need to use the same index for fnames () as for numbers [].
The function returns a dataframe, with lapply intended to enter the dataframe result of each file with its corresponding number in a list.

In this way I create the list of names

```
x<-list.files(pattern=".txt")
```

This is the array of numbers:

```
n<-c(4,4,12,6,3,6,8,32,4,4,9,5,5,6,8,3,6,7,3,6,5,3,5)
```

I do not know how to execute the function with those two parameters to get a list with all the results as if I were running lapply with it.

Comment: Are you looking for `mapply()` ?

Comment: `lapply(seq_along(letters), function(i) paste(letters[i], LETTERS[i]))` or for your case `lapply(seq_along(x), function(i) FUNCTION(x[i], n[i]))`